# Sound issues in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, jar, javasound

I have a very weird issue I cant fix.

I'm currently making a game and I want sound in the game. It is supposed to be run as a jar file and the game works perfectly fine when running it from eclipse.

The SoundPlayer is part of an external jar library that I use in the game. It then takes a name, a folder and plays the sound. The sound is located in a sub-folder of the folder where the FTSound object class is. I've checked the jar, and the sound files are included and they are in the same place as in eclipse. Now to the weird issue I've come across:

When I run the jar file by double-clicking it, everything works except the sound. It is completely missing. However, if I start the jar via cmd, the sound works fine. It is the exact same jar.

Any ideas? I'd much appreciate your help!

The sound is played with the following code:

```
public static void playSound(final FTSound sound) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound.getClass().getResource(sound.getFolderName() + "/" + sound.getSoundName()));
                clip.open(inputStream);
                clip.start(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas come to mind. You said you're using eclipse.  When you extract your files to the .jar, be sure that your audio files are all extracted to the same place.  If you are clicking on the .jar outside of the directory which contains your sound files and it's not a shortcut, but your run inside the same directory in the cmd, this could cause the issue you have described.  Although it doesn't really fix the issue, a workaround I would suggest is writing a bat to start your game at the command prompt. this will give you a clickable file which also  plays the sound. I don't see any issues in your code, and if you have gotten the sound to play, then there probably aren't any. One other thing: the clip object can't run sound well for more than a few seconds.  If you're looking for a sound effect, it's great, but otherwise, you should try using this method:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    SourceDataLine soundLine;
    public void run()
    {
      soundLine = null;
          int BUFFER_SIZE = 64*1024;  // 64 KB

              // Set up an audio input stream piped from the sound file.
              try {
                 AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("title.wav"));
                 AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
                 DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
                 soundLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                 soundLine.open(audioFormat);
                 soundLine.start();
                 int nBytesRead = 0;
                 byte[] sampledData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                 while (nBytesRead != -1) 
                 {
                    nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(sampledData, 0, sampledData.length);
                    if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                    {
                       // Writes audio data to the mixer via this source data line.
                       soundLine.write(sampledData, 0, nBytesRead);
                    }

                 }
              } catch (Exception ex) 
              {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
              }finally 
              {
                 soundLine.drain();
                 soundLine.close();
              }
        }
}).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure how I'm going to fix this though. I experimented for a while trying your solution as well and now i get sound when i double-click the jar. The problem now is that the sound is working for a while, and then all of a sudden it wipes out all sound on the computer, such that I need to reboot it. I think my sound card might be the cause, I am not sure though.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like an issue specific to your computer. This method is funny sometimes, though.  On my friend's computer, it turns his sound on if it's off; he has an alienware.  On my Toshiba, however, it works perfectly fine.  I have no idea why, though.